# Plotting a path in a vector field

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to make a visual representation of the curve $y=x^{2}$, with $x\in\left[0,1\right]$ in the vector field defined by $\vec{F}=\left[-y,x\right]$.

However, as far as I can tell there does not seem to be any facility which allows me to do this in Mathematica (I've looked through as much of the documentation as I could find which seemed pertinent).

I know how to do each of these separately, e.g.

```
Plot[x^2,{x,0,1}]
VectorPlot[{-y,x},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]
```

However, I am unsure how I can combine these two plots (or plot them both at the same time).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should make use of [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html?q=Show&lang=en) and appropriate options   e.g. we added `PlotRange`, `AspectRatio` etc. :

```
Show[{ Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> 3, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker @ Green}],
       VectorPlot[{-y, x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I was looking for! +1

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `Show` you might prefer the paradigm of David Park's *Presentations* package:

```
<< Presentations`

Draw2D[{VectorDraw[{-y, x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
        Darker@Green, Draw[x^2, {x, -3, 3}]},
       PlotRange->3, Axes->True]
```